# SQL - finding out the 5 highest numbers in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some tables that all contain information about books, such as titles, pages, price, royalty, etc.
I would like to use these tables to find the 5 authors that have the highest royalty rates.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE authors
  (
  au_id    CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  au_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  au_lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  phone    VARCHAR(12)         ,
  address  VARCHAR(20)         ,
  city     VARCHAR(15)         ,
  state    CHAR(2)             ,
  zip      CHAR(5)             ,
  CONSTRAINT pk_authors PRIMARY KEY (au_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE royalties
  (
  title_id     CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  advance      DECIMAL(9,2)         ,
  royalty_rate DECIMAL(5,2)         ,
  CONSTRAINT pk_royalties PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So far, I can only select the highest royalty rates. I tried using the TOP (5) function, but that did not work for me. My code is below.

```
SELECT au_fname, au_lname
FROM authors
WHERE au_id IN
(SELECT au_id
FROM title_authors
WHERE title_id IN
(SELECT title_id
FROM royalties
WHERE royalty_rate = (SELECT MAX(royalty_rate) FROM royalties)))
```

How can I go about finding the 5 authors that have the highest royalty rates?

Comment: I added the tag for MySQL because the syntax is MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support the TOP keyword. Some databases other than MySQL (e.g. SQL Server, Teradata, et al.) do support that syntax.

MySQL provides similar functionality with the LIMIT keyword.

```
 SELECT t.foo
   FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.bar DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

---

As far as getting the result, I strongly recommend you use join operations:

```
  SELECT a.au_fname
       , a.au_lname
    FROM authors a
    JOIN title_authors t 
      ON t.au_id = a.au_id
    JOIN royalties r
      ON r.title_id = t.title_id
   ORDER BY r.royalty_rate DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

Note that if an author has two (or more) titles with the highest royalty_rate, that author will be returned multiple times.

If you want five *different* authors, find the maximum royalty rate for each author, and order by that.

```
  SELECT a.au_fname
       , a.au_lname
    FROM authors a
    JOIN title_authors t 
      ON t.au_id = a.au_id
    JOIN royalties r
      ON r.title_id = t.title_id
   GROUP BY a.au_id
   ORDER BY MAX(r.royalty_rate) DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

If more than five authors have the same highest royalty_rate, then which five of those authors is indeterminate. You could add additional expressions to the ORDER BY clause to make the result more deterministic.

```
   ORDER BY MAX(r.royalty_rate) DESC, a.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use joins and aggregation:

```
SELECT a.au_fname, a.au_lname
FROM authors a JOIN
     title_authors ta
     USING (au_id) JOIN    
     royalties r
     USING (title_id)
ORDER BY royalty_rate DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

MySQL uses `LIMIT` to fetch the first five rows.